# pip install Valuerror while installing saleor on Ubuntu 14

Tags: python, django, saleor

I am setting up saleor on a new Ubuntu 14 Installation and when I run the following command:

pip install -r requirements.txt

I get an exception. I am not that knowledgeable on Linux and I am getting an error I don't understand how to address. I think it is complaining about the format of a specific line in the requirements.txt file but I don't know why.

The exception I get is this:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 262, in run
    for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options, session=session):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1632, in parse_requirements
    req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from, prereleases=getattr(options, "pre", None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 173, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 71, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2583, in scan_list
    "Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:]
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'uwsgi==2.0.17 ; platform_system != "Windows"', 'at', ' ; platform_system != "Windows"')

Storing debug log for failure in /home/edwin/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> Prerequisites Before you are ready to run Saleor you will need
>   additional software installed on your computer.
>
> Python 3 Saleor requires Python 3.4 or later. A compatible version
>   comes preinstalled with most current Linux systems. If that is not the
>   case consult your distribution for instructions on how to install
>   Python 3.6 or 3.7.
>   (https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/installation-linux.html)

And FYI: Latest LTS version version of Ubuntu is [18.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). The one in your system is 4+ years old.

Comment: This was the line that was causing the error: uwsgi==2.0.17 ; platform_system != "Windows"

Comment: I commented out the part after the version and that took care of the error. uwsgi==2.0.17 #; platform_system != "Windows"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above ubuntu 14 is very old and since you are using the newer version of saleor. There are compatibility issues. Upgrade to ubuntu 18 or ateast 16 to avoid these errors